# how to create text type writer effect with jQuery/javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

how to create text type writer effect with jQuery /javascript ?

i have tried to google,and found jtypewritter,
 but the Demo page given on [**`jQuery Plugin jtypewriter`**](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/jTypeWriter) not working / opening.

link : http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/jTypeWriter

[**`project's home page`**](http://www.dummwiam.com/jTypeWriter) also not working.

**Questions :**

1. How can i create text type writer effect with jQuery or java script
   ?
2. Is there any way to have same effects via any other tricks ?

Comment: Since there is no example on plugin's page, could you be more specific, what is "text type writer effect"?

Comment: same as our commad prompt (cmd).

Comment: so a textarea with a relevant font???

Comment: @Archer as we see in news channel website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume by `text type writer effect`, you mean the one in the Microsoft PowerPoint presentation slideshow animations :)

i.e. random colored text appear left to right with a little delay.

you can create your own. See this very simply (and ugly) demonstration by me:

```
var data="this is the data to be shown in effect";
var index=0;

var cursor="<span id='cursor'>_</span>";
$('.content').append(cursor);

function test(){
    //Clear the interval once entire characters are processed 
    if(index>=data.length-1){
        clearInterval(T);
    }

    //Generate random color
    var hue = 'rgb('
            + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ','
            + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ','
            + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ')';

    //wrap each of the characters in a span tag with the currently generated 
    //random style color. 
    _span = '<span style="color:'+hue+'">'+data[index]+'</span>';

    //and append the span just before the cursor
    $('#cursor').before(_span);
    index++;
}

//call the function repeatedly, till all the characters are processed, hence
//setInterval(code,duration) 
var T=setInterval("test()",200);
```

see this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/pSUk6/5/)

If you want to increase the animation effect, simply reduce the Interval in setInterval and vice-versa. Also, you can make it more elegent, by prototyping it.

It should give you an idea.

For restarting. simply do this, instead of Clearing the interval

```
if(index>=data.length-1){
        $('span').not('#cursor').remove();
        index=0;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pSUk6/6/)

Comment: can we add underscore at the end ?

Comment: I already did. see the Fiddle :)

Comment: looks great ! can it be automatic restart when finished ?

Comment: that's very simple. once you have processed all the characters, just remove all the span except cursor and set the index to 0, instead of clearing the interval. [see this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pSUk6/6/)

Answer (score 1):

This is the example of how to create text typewriter effects with jQuery

demo: http://jsbin.com/araget/5/

**plugin**:

```
(function ($) {
  // writes the string
  //
  // @param jQuery $target
  // @param String str
  // @param Numeric cursor
  // @param Numeric delay
  // @param Function cb
  // @return void
  function typeString($target, str, cursor, delay, cb) {
    $target.html(function (_, html) {
      return html + str[cursor];
    });

    if (cursor < str.length - 1) {
      setTimeout(function () {
        typeString($target, str, cursor + 1, delay, cb);
      }, delay);
    }
    else {
      cb();
    }
  }

  // clears the string
  //
  // @param jQuery $target
  // @param Numeric delay
  // @param Function cb
  // @return void
  function deleteString($target, delay, cb) {
    var length;

    $target.html(function (_, html) {
      length = html.length;
      return html.substr(0, length - 1);
    });

    if (length > 1) {
      setTimeout(function () {
        deleteString($target, delay, cb);
      }, delay);
    }
    else {
      cb();
    }
  }

  // jQuery hook
  $.fn.extend({
    teletype: function (opts) {
      var settings = $.extend({}, $.teletype.defaults, opts);

      return $(this).each(function () {
        (function loop($tar, idx) {
          // type
          typeString($tar, settings.text[idx], 0, settings.delay, function () {
            // delete
            setTimeout(function () {
              deleteString($tar, settings.delay, function () {
                loop($tar, (idx + 1) % settings.text.length);
              });
            }, settings.pause);
          });

        }($(this), 0));
      });
    }
  });

  // plugin defaults  
  $.extend({
    teletype: {
      defaults: {
        delay: 100,
        pause: 5000,
        text: []
      }
    }
  });
}(jQuery));
```

**html**:

```
<span id="target"></span>
<span id="cursor"></span> <!-- used for the blinking cursor effect -->
```

**init**:

```
$('#target').teletype({
  text: [
    'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,',
    'sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore',
    'magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et',
    'accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd',
    'gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit',
    'amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,',
    'sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore',
    'magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam',
    'et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren,',
    'no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.'
  ]
});

$('#cursor').teletype({
  text: ['_', ' '],
  delay: 0,
  pause: 500
});
```